# mysql : dynamic conversion of columns into rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Need to convert this...

```
ID  C1  C2  C3  C4
1   a   aa  aaa 28-02-2014
2   b   bb  bbb 21-03-2014
```

into this...

```
ID      Column     Value
1        C1          a
1        C2          aa
1        C3          aaa
1        C4          28-02-2014
2        C1          b
2        C2          bb
2        C3          bbb
2        C4          21-03-2014
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a UNION statement. 
This is os if you only have a few columns but would suggest a procedural loop if there were multiple columns

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT id, 'c1' as column, c1 as val FROM test
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT id, 'c2' as column, c2 as val FROM test
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT id, 'c3' as column, c3 as val FROM test
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT id, 'c4' as column, c4 as val FROM test)t1
ORDER BY id asc, column asc;
```

Answer (score -2):

You won't be able to do it with a query, as far as I know, but Mohammad at boynux.com put together a [stored procedure](http://www.boynux.com/creating-pivot-reports-in-mysql/), though it's somewhat more tailored for his specific conditions.